# Show user log in files

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am currently working on a file upload system using ASP.NET c#.

I have a problem whereby I am able to see the files of all user when I run my website. However when I specify to only show the logged in user files, it works but does not show on the webpage unless I upload a file first, then it shows the users files. So it is 50% working but I just need some help in why the files do not show up straight away.

The code bellow is the code that I have created to show the files....

```
 private void PopulateUploadedFiles()
    {
        using (simpleEntities1 dc = new simpleEntities1())
        {
            List<UploadedFile> alluserFiles = dc.UploadedFiles.ToList();/*Where (a => a.UserName.Equals(user))*///works but doesn't load up automatically.

            DataList1.DataSource = alluserFiles;
            DataList1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the `user` variable defined in your commented out code? Is this only being set once you have uploaded a file maybe?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to include that...(user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;). It shows the user files, but only when i upload a new file.

Comment: Would help to see it in context. Are you sure `user` is being set when following the path in without posting a file?

Comment: Yes, it has been set. The version I have shown is to show that it works when showing all user files, but it only works when a file is uploaded when specified to only user logged in files..
`user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                List<UploadedFile> alluserFiles = dc.UploadedFiles.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(user)).ToList();//works but doesn't load up automaticlly.
                DataList1.DataSource = alluserFiles;
                DataList1.DataBind();`